# Tensor slicing conditions for assignement

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

Why does this
'''tensor_ques[1:3,1]=0'''
work 
and this
'''tensor_ques[1:3,1] =[0,0]'''
does not work
tensor_ques is a torch.tensor()

I know [0,0] is not a tensor then why does =0 work fine

Comment: Try `tensor_ques[1:3,1] = torch.tensor([0,0])`

Comment: I know that works. My question is why doesnt this work. when just =0 works

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `[0,0]` is a list, and torch does not allow you to assign a list to a tensor. It'll only work if the item being assigned is also a tensor, i.e. `tensor_ques[1:3,1] = torch.tensor([0,0])`.